# How does one aggregate and summarize data quickly?

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I have a dataset whose headers look like so:

```
PID Time Site Rep Count
```

I want sum the `Count` by `Rep` for each `PID x Time x Site combo`

on the resulting data.frame, I want to get the mean value of `Count` for `PID x Time x Site` combo.

Current function is as follows:

```
dummy <- function (data)
{
A<-aggregate(Count~PID+Time+Site+Rep,data=data,function(x){sum(na.omit(x))})
B<-aggregate(Count~PID+Time+Site,data=A,mean)
return (B)
}
```

This is painfully slow (original data.frame is `510000     20)`. Is there a way to speed this up with plyr?

Comment: You don't state why you have the A<- line. Are you making sure there's a weighting there? To meet your stated criterion you only need the B<- line. (plyr won't make it any faster but data.frame will)

Comment: Right, data.table was super fast (and am so glad I learned about it). A was redundant, yeah.

Comment: Then the A line would explain why your aggregate was so slow. If you just run B it should go pretty quick.  The data.table command provided also removes REP.  It's that you were basically making a new data frame in A the same size as the original that was slowing things down so much.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should look at the package `data.table` for faster aggregation operations on large data frames. For your problem, the solution would look like:

```
library(data.table)
data_t = data.table(data_tab)
ans = data_t[,list(A = sum(count), B = mean(count)), by = 'PID,Time,Site']
```

Comment: Wow, data.table does work really fast! How to get these lists A and B sorted by `PID`, `Time` and `Site` (just the way aggregate does it)?

Comment: @Sangram use `keyby` instead of `by`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  What is the fastest way to group aggregate for very large data tables?  Is the above it?  When you use keys, subsetting uses binary search which is faster is my understanding.  Though it makes the code a bit less readable

Comment: @robertevansanders, It is very likely that it is faster to do aggregations on a keyed data, but I don't think I ever tested it.

Answer (score 9):

Let's see how fast `data.table` is and compare to using `dplyr`. Thishis would be roughly the way to do it in `dplyr`.

```
data %>% group_by(PID, Time, Site, Rep) %>%
    summarise(totalCount = sum(Count)) %>%
    group_by(PID, Time, Site) %>% 
    summarise(mean(totalCount))
```

Or perhaps this, depending on exactly how the question is interpreted:

```
    data %>% group_by(PID, Time, Site) %>%
        summarise(totalCount = sum(Count), meanCount = mean(Count)
```

Here is a full example of these alternatives versus @Ramnath proposed answer and the one @David Arenburg proposed in the comments , which I think is equivalent to the second `dplyr` statement.

```
nrow <- 510000
data <- data.frame(PID = sample(letters, nrow, replace = TRUE), 
                   Time = sample(letters, nrow, replace = TRUE),
                   Site = sample(letters, nrow, replace = TRUE),
                   Rep = rnorm(nrow),
                   Count = rpois(nrow, 100))


library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

Rprof(tf1 <- tempfile())
ans <- data %>% group_by(PID, Time, Site, Rep) %>%
    summarise(totalCount = sum(Count)) %>%
    group_by(PID, Time, Site) %>% 
    summarise(mean(totalCount))
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tf1)  #reports 1.68 sec sampling time

Rprof(tf2 <- tempfile())
ans <- data %>% group_by(PID, Time, Site, Rep) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(Count), meanCount = mean(Count)) 
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tf2)  # reports 1.60 seconds

Rprof(tf3 <- tempfile())
data_t = data.table(data)
ans = data_t[,list(A = sum(Count), B = mean(Count)), by = 'PID,Time,Site']
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tf3)  #reports 0.06 seconds

Rprof(tf4 <- tempfile())
ans <- setDT(data)[,.(A = sum(Count), B = mean(Count)), by = 'PID,Time,Site']
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tf4)  #reports 0.02 seconds
```

The data table method is much faster, and the `setDT` is even faster!

Comment: It would be even faster if you would use `setDT(data)[,.(A = sum(Count), B = mean(Count)), by = 'PID,Time,Site']` instead of creating a copy

Comment: Have you checked [50-100GB benchmarks](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping)?

Comment: Not yet, seemed more interesting in context  to use a data set about the size the OP reported.